# Removing Duplicates from a Sorted Linked List

Tags: c++, data-structures, while-loop, linked-list

I've written the following code in C++ which removes duplicates from a sorted Linked List.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
    public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
    
    Node(int data)
    {
        this->data = data;
        this->next = NULL;
    }
};


void push(Node* &head, Node* &tail, int data)
{
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        Node* newNode = new Node(data);
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
        return;
    }
    
    else
    {
        Node* newNode = new Node(data);
        tail -> next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
}

void print(Node* &head)
{
    Node *temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<temp->data<<" ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void removeDuplicates(Node* &head)
{
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Empty LL!";
        return;
    }
    
    if(head -> next == NULL) 
    {
        cout << "Single Node in LL" << endl;
        return ;
    }
    
    Node* curr = head;
    
    while(curr!=NULL)
    {
        if(curr->next!=NULL && (curr->data == curr->next->data))
        {
            Node* temp = curr->next;
            curr->next = curr->next->next;
            temp->next = NULL;
            delete temp;
            
        }
        
        else
        {
             curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    Node* head = NULL;
    Node* tail = NULL;
    
    push(head, tail, 25);
    push(head, tail, 50);
    push(head, tail, 50);
    push(head, tail, 67);
    print(head);
    cout<<endl;
    removeDuplicates(head);
    print(head);
    return 0;
}
```

While the code functions well, my doubt is that in the 'if' block, after deleting the duplicate node, why aren't we updating the value of curr like curr = curr -> next to send it to the while loop again. How else would while know what the updated value of curr is?

PS: Still a beginner in C++ :)

Comment: I have a serious headache so my analysis could be wrong. The loop looks correct. It says if the next node exists and contains the same value as the current node delete it and switch the link to point to the next->next node which is correct. You don't need to advance the current because you want to test the value between the current and what was the next -> next.

Comment: The `removeDuplicates` function removes the node ahead of where we are now if they are equal:  ie if we have a list of nodes: A -> B -> C -> D, it checks if A == B and removes B if they are the same.  Now next time round the loop it is still on A as it needs to check if A == C before moving on.

Answer (score 5):

If you remove the next node from the list, there may still be more duplicates left. If you'd advance `curr`, you'd only erase every other duplicate element.

The following happens with the current code (`^` marks `curr`, `---` the next iteration and any non-number node content is just there to mark the different nodes)

```
1(a) -> 1(b) -> 1(c) -> 2(d)
^
---
1(a) -> 1(c) -> 2(d)
^
---
1(a) -> 2(d)
^
---
1(a) -> 2(d)
        ^
```

Your suggested change would result in the following

```
1(a) -> 1(b) -> 1(c) -> 2(d)
^
---
1(a) -> 1(c) -> 2(d)
        ^
---
1(a) -> 1(c) -> 2(d)
                ^
```

Answer (score 3):

> why aren't we updating the value of `curr` like `curr = curr -> next`

Because you want `curr` unaffected by the removal so that you can compare it with the next node after the removed one too. There may be more than one duplicate in the list and you want all but the first one removed.